# php undefined variable session_register issue

Tags: php, session-variables, session-cookies

There was a php project which was already in live server. Now my work is to change some style issues. So for that I just downloaded all the files from the server along with the database. After that I made all the necessary setup on my localhost(LAMP). Now when I browse the page I got some error like

```
Notice: Undefined variable: _session_register in path to the folder/file session.php on line 8
```

Now on line 8 I can see this code

```
$_session_register["esb2b_username"];
$_session_register["esb2b_userid"];
$_session_register["esb2b_memtype"];
$_session_register["esb2b_adv_id"];
$_session_register["esb2b_adv_email"];
$_session_register["lang"];
```

After searching over google I came to know that session_register in php is deprecated. So what will be the best solution to solve this issue in a fine way? Any help and suggestions will be appreciable. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There's a function called `session_register` that is deprecated, but what you have in the question is a variable.  You are getting this notice because you are using array-access on it and it is undefined.  This works, but it is better practice to define it as an empty array first.

Comment: so can you tell me how to solve this issue in a good way..I have around 1000 files..so what will be the good way to solve this issue?

Comment: Do a lot of really hard work .. or just ignore it if it's working.  It's just a notice.  You can fix it as you find it

Answer (score 0):

`$_session_register` this is wrong use `$_SESSION`

`session_register` is a function which is deprecated. (Way which you written now is also wrong)

`$_session_register["esb2b_username"];` change it to `$_SESSION["esb2b_username"] = "";`